# How to integrate OneDrive Api to IOS App in swift? I am done registering my app and have client Id

Tags: ios, swift, onedrive

import UIKit
import OneDriveSDK

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var authenticatedOdClient : ODClient?
var authenticatedDrive : ODDrive?
var authenticatedItem : ODItem?
var itemId : ODItem?

@IBAction func goToOneDrive(sender: AnyObject) {

    ODClient.clientWithCompletion { (client, error) -> Void in
        if ((error == nil)){
            self.authenticatedOdClient = client
         self.getUserDriveData()

        }
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    ODClient.setMicrosoftAccountAppId("0000000040186848", scopes: ["onedrive.readwrite"])

}


func getUserDriveData(){
    self.authenticatedOdClient?.drive().request().getWithCompletion({ (ODdrive, error) -> Void in

        if(error == nil){
            self.authenticatedDrive = ODdrive
            print(self.authenticatedDrive?.owner)
            print(self.authenticatedDrive?.driveType)
            print(self.authenticatedDrive?.quota)
            print(self.authenticatedDrive?.id)
           print( self.authenticatedDrive?.driveType)
            //self.authenticatedOdClient?.drive().items().request().

        }
        else{
            print("error is", error)
        }

        self.getUserRootFolder()
    })
}

func getUserRootFolder(){

    self.authenticatedOdClient?.drive().request().getWithCompletion({ (drive, error) -> Void in


    })

    self.authenticatedOdClient?.drive().items("root").request().getWithCompletion({ (root, error) -> Void in



    })
    self.authenticatedOdClient?.root().itemByPath("Documents").request().getWithCompletion({ (item, error) -> Void in

        print(item.id)


    })
```

self.authenticatedOdClient?.drive().items("root/Documents/Akshat's Notebook").request().getWithCompletion({ (ODItem, error) -> Void in

```
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

}